# Filter on Sent Mail folder and delete filtered records

Tags: gmail

These are the criteria I need to remove mails from Sent Item folder:

```
1.) Subject: OMS Messages - Confirmation message
2.) before:2013-08-31
```

I am using this:

```
label:Sent Mail : Subject : OMS Messages - Confirmation message : before:2013-08-31
```

But this filter is fetching all records from other labels also.

How can I use this filter to delete items from Sent Item folder?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Instead of `label:Sent Mail` use `in:sent`.

## Remarks

- If you only want to deleted individual messages rather than threads, be sure that you have disabled the conversation view.
- Instead of creating a filter, you are doing a advanced search
- Filters only works in incoming messages at delivering time.

## References

[Advanced Search - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)